# How to trigger FireBase inappmessage at particular time when we are in app

Tags: android, firebase-in-app-messaging

I placed fire-base in app messaging in my app. While open the app i got in app message correctly when sent from console. now how to send in app message when user opened 3 times or any other condition he should get that in app message? please help.

Comment: You can keep the app open count in sharedpref , when condition satisfy trigger inappmessage.

Comment: i dont know how to trigger from coding. Please send any sample.Thanks

Comment: If your requirement is to call inappmessage when user opens app for third time. create a sharedpref, increment it every time user opens the app , check if it is equal to 3. if so call inappmessage.  Go through this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/TriggerEventListener) for more details.

Comment: @PavanShetty u said to call Inappmessage right. I want code how to call inappmessage. for now i send messages from console but from app how to send message